# Express js route handling

Tags: node.js, express

In my application I've set the **static folder** in which there is an 'index.html' file.

I want to render that file on route **/profile**

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. Take a look at the following code.

```
var app=require('express')();
app.use("/profile", lib.express.static("./public"));
```

Here `./public` is the original location of your folder containing the `index.html` file.